# What is decentralized-distributed system? Why Blockchain is decentralized-distributed system?

Tags: blockchain, distributed-system, decentralized-applications

**Distributed System** have no single authority and each node is connected to every other node while in **Decentralized System** each node is not connected to every other node as it also have no single authority. Then how Blockchain is a decentralized-distributed system?

Answer (score 0):

Distributed systems mean that more than one computer is used to perfom a specific task. They can be centralised, like in cloud computing where users connect to a group of computers that are owned by a specific cloud provider, or descentralized like peer to peer systems like BitTorrent where files are shared between computers without the need of a centralized resource. Blockchain is also a form of peer to peer system.

Comment: So it will be a decentralized system. How it have both decentralization and distribution properties?

Comment: A decentralized system is a subset of a distributed system. If it has descentralization properties it must have distributed properties as well.